# Set all bool property values of an object

Tags: c#, reflection

Consider the following object

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool RecordExist { get; set; }

    public bool HasDamage { get; set; }

    public bool FirstCheckCompleted { get; set; }

    public bool SecondCheckCompleted { get; set; }

    //10 more bool properties plus other properties
}
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is set the property value to `true` to all the `bool` properties apart from `RecordExist` and `HasDamage`. To achieve this I have gone ahead and created the following method.

```
public T SetBoolPropertyValueOfObject<T>(string[] propNames, Type propertyType, object value)
{
   PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

   T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

    if(propNames.Length > 0 || propNames != null)
        foreach (var property in properties)
         foreach (string pName in propNames)
            if (property.PropertyType == propertyType && property.Name != pName)
                 property.SetValue(obj, value, null);

        return obj;
}
```

The above method is then called as follows:

```
public Foo Foo()
{
   string[] propsToExclude = new string[]
   {
      "RecordExist",
      "HasDamage"
   };

    var foo = SetBoolPropertyValueOfObject<Foo>(propsToExclude, typeof(bool), true);

    return foo;
}
```

The method does not work as expected. When inside the `foreach` loop first time the `RecordExist` prop is set to false but when it goes into the loop again `RecordExist` is set to true and the rest of the props are set to true as well including `HasDamage`.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your logic is wrong:

- outer loop wants to set e.g. `RecordExist`
- inner loop, first step says "oh it's equal to `RecordExist`, I don't set"
- inner loop, second step: "oh `RecordExist` is not equal to `HasDamage` so I set"

You just want to know if `propNames` **contains** the property name:

```
if(propNames.Length > 0 || propNames != null)
      foreach (var property in properties)
          if (property.PropertyType == propertyType && 
              !propNames.Contains(property.Name))
             property.SetValue(obj, value, null);
```

But note that this only sets any property if you provided names to exclude (the outer `if`). I don't think that's what you want.

So the final code could look like:

```
foreach (var property in properties.Where(p => 
                p.PropertyType == propertyType &&
                propNames?.Contains(p.Name) != true)) // without the 'if' we need a null-check
     property.SetValue(obj, value, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a single loop:

```
    foreach (var property in properties)
        if (property.PropertyType == propertyType && !propNames.Contains(property.Name))
             property.SetValue(obj, value, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
 PropertyInfo[] properties = Object.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
       if (property.PropertyType==typeof(Boolean) && propNames.Contains(somestring))
        {
            property.SetValue(Object, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?